# What do "Collector" specialists do?

Tags: disgaea-2

I've been playing Disgaea 2 a lot lately, and while grinding items through the Item World I encountered a few specialists named "Collector".

The [wiki page on specialists](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Disgaea_2_Specialists) does not, unfortunately, explain what a Collector does aside from "increase rarity" without explaining what rarity means in this context.

Can anyone here elucidate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one increases the rarity of the item it is contained in by 1 (reduces the rarity number by 1). The rarity in this case is the number from 0-255 that determines if an item is common, rare, or legendary. The biggest use of these is to change the rarity of equipment with rarity numbers that are near each other in order to get them to match to give you a bonus to the stats granted by each item.

Comment: I thought common/rare/legendary was mostly a function of how many specialists can fit in an item. Can you provide an example for how this matching bonus works?

Comment: I can't remember the exact percents as it's been a while since I played, but if you have say a pair of glasses and an armor each with 85 rarity equipped on the same character then those items will each get a boost to its stats (in this case int/hit for glasses and def for the armor). Usually you'd only care about matching rarities end game with legendary gear as you'll be swapping out equipment throughout the game and it wouldn't be worth the trouble.

Comment: So noted. I'll just drop the free collectors I find on spare subpoenas until I've a use for them, then.